# How to change brightness on CRT display through the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, brightness

I have a Debian Linux desktop and a CRT display. I want to change the screen's brightness without using the monitor's brightness controls. How can I do this? Is this possible in the command line or is there an application to be installed?

Comment: So you have a desktop with an external monitor and you want to control the backlight, right? It is connected by VGA cable? I don't think there is a way to do that. Most LCD backlight controls are for laptops and handhelds that have direct access (I/O) to the backlight controller. I don't think there is a control path via the VGA interface for that.

Comment: ADditional info: I'm using CRT monitor.

Comment: @NeilvertNoval Instead of commenting with add. info, add the info to the original question. The fact that it is a CRT monitor should be declared in the question title itself.

Answer (score 18):

Look under `/sys/class/backlight` for the appropriate files to frob.

```
echo -n 6 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Comment: my /sys/class/backlight is an empty directory.

Comment: Works, but my path is `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` and my range goes up to 15. (Fedora 17 64bit)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams same problem as Neilvert Noval

Comment: This requires root access, which I think makes this unusable.

Comment: @oneself: Non-root access was never a part of the question.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that is implied. No one wants to put in their sudo password every time they need to change screen brightness. This answer is _technically_ correct, but some of the other ones are better (e.g. xbacklight which does not require root).

Comment: @oneself: How do you know it isn't being run by e.g. systemd, which runs as root *anyway*...

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with sudo. You really need to use the `su` command first to get it working.

Comment: It works fine with sudo. The trick is to perform the redirection under sudo and not just the echo.

Comment: On a chromebook: echo -n 937 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

Answer (score 16):

`$ sudo apt-get install xbacklight`

How to set brightness to 50%

`$ xbacklight -set 50`

How to increase brightness 10%

`$ xbacklight -inc 10`

How to decrease brightness 10%

`$ xbacklight -dec 10`

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/149265/7915)

Comment: `jcomeau@aspire:~$ xbacklight -set 50` gives error message: No outputs have backlight property

Comment: it changes the contrast, not the brightness; it doesn't save power.

Answer (score 8):

You need to control the monitor over DDC. See http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/ for one program that lets you do this.

Comment: Very good, thanks for the tip! I wrote a program with it, look at it on this page.

Comment: Project was moved to github: https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have hardware support for changing the brightness of your monitor you could use 
 the command **xrandr** together with its option flags **--output** and **--brightness**, as can be seen in my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45153/is-there-an-alternative-to-redshift-and-f-lux-which-only-dims-the-screen/48952#48952) to a similar question on askubuntu.com

Comment: This is actually very nice!

Answer (score 3):

You could give [this solution](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/10/25/ajust-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-works-at-dell-1501/) a try:

```
echo -n 100 > /proc/acpi/video/VGA/LCD/brightness
```

Also, in the comments, there are some hints what to do alternatively if it doesn't work (f.e. using `GLX0` instead of `VGA`.

EDIT: As this doesn't seem to help, another user in the comments suggests to install `xbacklight` and calling `xbacklight -set 100`.

EDIT2: And another one says if you don't have a video folder, try `sudo modprobe video`.

Comment: I checked on this before posting, but I have no video folder on that path.

Comment: modprobe video -> command not found

Comment: I already installed xbacklight, but when I do `xbacklight -set 100.` it says `No outputs have backlight property`

Comment: No *video* folder + `sudo modprobe video` doesn't does anything.

Answer (score 3):

After searching around, I think I found a pretty good way to get this done on most laptops. The first command gets the name of your screen, something like LVDS1. If this does not work, try getting the name of your screen with `xrandr --current`. There are probably more elegant ways to do this, the sed command removes everything after the first space, the head and tail commands simply remove everything except the second line of the output. The second line uses the screen name to change the brightness to 1.0. This can be set to almost anything, including 0.0 for a black screen or 50.0 for a completely white screen, but I think 1.0 is the desired value here.

```
screenName=$(xrandr --current | sed s/\ .*// | head -n2 | tail -n1);
xrandr --output $screenName --brightness 1.0
```

The command below sets the brightness to the maximum allowed brightness, as I noticed that just setting it to '100' does not simply work, at least not on all systems.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -n $(cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness) > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness'
```

This worked on multiple laptops running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Mind you, this will do it in software by modifiying the pixel values. It will not actually dim the display.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small program I wrote to control the brightness on my laptop for Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. Look at explanations inside (file /usr/local/dreamcolor2/README in the tarball):

http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~edouard.thiel/tar/brightness-dreamcolor2.tgz

It uses ddccontrol on i2c buses and works great for my configuration:

```
- HP ELiteBook 8770w
- NVidia Quadro K3000M
- HP DreamColor 2 Monitor, full HD
- Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS x86_64, kernel 3.8.0-34-generic
- Nvidia Driver Version: 319.32
- Unity desktop
```

I tried every other solutions in this page and this is the only one which actually worked for me. Another solution was to run the HP Mobile Display Assistant (downloaded on HP site) but it is only given as rpm, no deb package; it has to be tweaked a little bit to work and is rather slow, and does not work with fn keys.

My script allows to control the brightness by the command line and by the fn keys.
Please tell me if it works for you out of the box or if you have to change the i2c device in the script.

Answer (score 0):

CRT's (Cathode Ray Tube) don't have backlights. LCD's do have backlights.
Adjusting the brightness on a CRT involves changing the signal going to it, unlike a LCD.

CRT's use the maximum amount of power on white screens, because the electron guns use more power to emit more electrons, while LCD's spend the most power on black screens, because all transistors are on flipping the polarity of liquid crystal blocking the light coming from the backlight.

Any utility that can trigger DPMS should work to put the monitor into sleep mode with many of the CRT's made in the mid to late 90's through to the end of production.

Comment: To elaborate a little more, CRTs emit light though the florescence  excitation of phosphors due to the electrons hitting it. Various different chemicals emitted different frequencies of light.

Comment: There are four DPMS modes that analog CRTs could be in, all controlled by the state of the VSync and HSYNC lines, ON is HSYNC and VSYNC both on, STANDBY is HSYNC off and VSYNC ON uses around 80% power, SUSPEND HSYNC on VSYNC off uses around 30W for the Energy Star rated monitors and OFF- both HSYNC AND VSYNC off. This used to work just fine with X, going back all the way to the XFree86 days, but I don't know if it still works.

Comment: You can query the state of DPMS with xset q, which, I think, is still a part of the standard X Windows set of programs. You can also set the time for DPMS with xset, as well as changing mouse and keyboard parameters.

Comment: For permanent changes, you should add        Option          "DPMS" to the "Monitor" section, and to the Server Layout section of xorg.conf something like         Option          "BlankTime"     "4"
        Option          "StandbyTime"   "0"
        Option          "SuspendTime"   "0"
        Option          "OffTime"       "5" with the times edited to your preference

Comment: Changing Brightness and Contrast on a analog monitor is done down on the other side of the RAMDAC, by opamps in the RAMDAC or or between the RAMDAC and VGA connector or on the monitor side by amps in the Monitor. Contrast is controlled by amplification of the signal, and Contrast is controlled by the Bias of the signal, so DC offset.

Comment: The  RGB colorspace is really ill-suited to the task, there is no headroom and you lose Gamut information.  HSV colorspace is better suited to adjusting brightness and contrast, YCbCr even better. It can get pretty involved depending on how deeply you look into it, a good in depth primer is chapter 3 of Andrew S. Glassner's 1400 page Principles of Digital Image Synthesis.

Comment: ON modern cards, the best way to do Contrast and Brightness correction is probably through the VideoLUT, the same way color correction is done. Unfortunately, both AMD and NVIdia are pretty closed about how to use that mechanism, possibly for product differentiation, got to make those Quadro and FireGL cards look like they can do more than the gaming cards, and also possibly out of fear of being sued by the color correction corps like Pantone

Comment: Another typo above Should be Brightness is controlled by amplification of the signal, and Contrast is controlled by the Bias of the signal, so DC offset.

Comment: And to finally answer, no not really with anything in X windows, but you can change it sortof, with xgamma which changes the gamma ramp, not really brightness, but close enough. Type in a terminal xgamma -gamma {value} Gamma values must be between  0.100 and 10.000