# Screen Brightness not permanent

Tags: display, brightness, fedora-15

I own a Lenovo Thinkpad SL400 and I dual boot Fedora 15 AND Windows 7 on my laptop. I am facing a problem with my fedora installation:

Whenever I reboot the computer, my screen brightness goes back to maximum. This does not happen with windows 7. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my own question here: https://superuser.com/a/256093/96551

I added a few lines to rc.local so that this script gets executed at startup, thus setting the required brightness.